# Getting Printer's Driver Version alongside Printer name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Hello :)

Hope you are doing fine today.

Well, I've been asked to pull out a report of all our Printers and the Drivers version they are utilizing (more than 1300 printers worldwide and 150+ Hosts).

At that point, I can retrieve most of the information I need.

Here's the code so far:

```
$ReportFileName = "c:\SAC_IS\printerreport.csv" 
$PrintServersList="C:\SAC_IS\servlist_TEST.txt" 

$servers =  Get-Content -Path $PrintServersList 
$allprinters = @() 
foreach( $server in $servers ){ 
Write-Host "checking $server ..." 
$printers = $null 
$printers = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Printer -computername $server | select Name,Shared,ShareName,Local, DriverName, PortName, @{n="HostName";e={$server}} ,@{n="Driver Version";e={Get-WmiObject Win32_PrinterDriver -ComputerName $server | select @{n="Version";e={(Get-Item $_.DriverPath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion}}}}, Location,Comment,SpoolEnabled,Published
$allprinters += $printers 
 } 

$allprinters | Export-CSV -Path $ReportFileName -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8
```

My problem here is that I'm unable to retrieve the driver's version that the printer's using:

[image: CSV Output]

Running the script returns no errors at all :/

Can an hand be given please? :D

Subsidiary question, why the hell is it taking like 5 minutes per Host. Can't this be quicker?

Thanks a lot to everyone that can help :)

Comment: `Get-PrinterDriver` will get you the Major version of the driver.

Comment: The major version is not the one I need to retrieve:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_PrinterDriver -ComputerName FS01 | select Name,@{n="Version";e={(Get-Item $_.DriverPath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion}}`

Give me as an output:

`Name                                                             Version
----                                                                   -------
TP Output Gateway PS,3,Windows x64       10.0.18362.387`

And this is the version I need to put in my export-csv ;)

Comment: Yoru comment seems to work, it is giving you version for each printer...can you please elaborate more

Comment: Yes, running this line alone in an empty ISE window works. But I'd like to "integrate" this command to the `$printers = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Printer...`one so all is exported in my final csv. 
As you can see on the post's picture the "Driver Version" column remains blank. I think my problem is the "commands" merging. I've tried many manipulations, without success though :D

Comment: Not sure of this cmdlet, you can do some thing like this $printers = get-somecmdlet|Select  some properties... in next line  $printers | add-member -noteproperty -name -value

Comment: You'll run into issues when there are multiple drivers on the server - you're not going to list the right one for each printer this way.

Comment: @Scepticalist, Is there then a "simple" way to achieve this? That is really the last value I'd need to gather from these FS :/

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way?

```
$servers | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentServer = $_
    Write-Host "Checking $CurrentServer_ ..." 
    $Drivers = Get-PrinterDriver -ComputerName $CurrentServer | Select-Object Name, @{n="DriverVersion";e={ $ver = $_.DriverVersion;(3..0 | ForEach-Object { ($ver -shr ($_ * 16)) -band 0xffff }) -join '.'}}

    Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Printer -Computername $CurrentServer | ForEach-Object {
        $ThisPrintDriverName = $_.DriverName
        $ThisDriver = $Drivers | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ThisPrintDriverName }

        [pscustomobject]@{Name = $_.Name
                        Shared = $_.Shared
                        ShareName = $_.ShareName
                        Local = $_.Local
                        DriverName = $_.DriverName
                        PortName = $_.PortName
                        HostName = $CurrentServer
                        Location = $_.Location
                        Comment = $_.Comment
                        SpoolEnabled = $_.SpoolEnabled
                        Published = $_.Published
                        Driver = $ThisDriver.Name
                        Version = $ThisDriver.DriverVersion
                        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies - a bug in the above, which I've now rectified

Comment: No worries ;) Gonna test that out and let you know shortly ^^

Answer (score 1):

Probably the main thing about your code is that, although you are working on remote machines, you use the **local** DriverPath to get the driver version and also do not specify the driver you are aiming for.

The code below uses a small helper function to get the driver version from the actual driver file on the server using the UNC path instead of the local path.
Also, I think by using a function here can make the code more readable.

To try and speed things up, I'm using `Get-CimInstance` instead of `Get-WmiObject` and collect the objects without adding to a predefined array:

```
$ReportFileName   = 'C:\SAC_IS\printerreport.csv' 
$PrintServersList = 'C:\SAC_IS\servlist_TEST.txt' 

function Get-PrinterProductVersion ($server, $printer) {
    $prn = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PrinterDriver -ComputerName $server | 
           Where-Object { ($_.Name -split ',')[0] -eq $($printer.DriverName) }
    if ($prn) { 
        # transform the local driver path into a UNC path
        $path = Join-Path -Path "\\$server" -ChildPath ($prn.DriverPath -replace ':', '$')
        (Get-Item $path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion 
    }
}

$allprinters = Get-Content -Path $PrintServersList | ForEach-Object {
    # capture the server name in a self-defined variable
    $server = $_
    Write-Host "checking server $server ..." 
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ComputerName $server | 
        Select-Object Name,Shared,ShareName,Local,DriverName,PortName, 
                      @{Name = "HostName"; Expression = { $server }},
                      @{Name = "Driver Version"; Expression = { Get-PrinterProductVersion $server $_ }}, 
                      Location,Comment,SpoolEnabled,Published
 } 

# output on screen
$allprinters

# output to CSV file
$allprinters | Export-CSV -Path $ReportFileName -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8
```

<sup>P.S. Personally, I wouldn't want a header with a space in its name like `"Driver Version"` but that's up to you</sup>

---

### Edit

I cannot test this myself, but perhaps you can speed this up if you let the servers themselves gather the wanted printer info.

Something like this:

```
$ReportFileName   = 'C:\SAC_IS\printerreport.csv' 
$PrintServersList = 'C:\SAC_IS\servlist_TEST.txt' 

# create a scriptblock for each server to execute
$scriptBlock = {
    function Get-PrinterProductVersion ($printer) {
        # or try with 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrinterDriver' if Get-CimInstance not available
        $prn = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PrinterDriver | 
               Where-Object { ($_.Name -split ',')[0] -eq $($printer.DriverName) }
        if ($prn) { (Get-Item $prn.DriverPath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion }
    }

    # or try with 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer' if Get-CimInstance not available
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | 
        Select-Object Name,Shared,ShareName,Local,DriverName,PortName, 
                      @{Name = "HostName"; Expression = { $env:COMPUTERNAME }},
                      @{Name = "Driver Version"; Expression = { Get-PrinterProductVersion $_ }}, 
                      Location,Comment,SpoolEnabled,Published


}

# create a list to gather all results from the servers
$allprinters = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

Get-Content -Path $PrintServersList | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "checking server $_ ..." 
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $printers = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ComputerName $_
        $allprinters.AddRange($printers)
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Server $_ cannot be reached"
    }
 } 

# output on screen
$allprinters

# output to CSV file
$allprinters | Export-CSV -Path $ReportFileName -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you meant :) Thanks a lot for this. But running you script throw me that error:
`Get-CimInstance : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. A DMTF resource URI was used to access a non-DMTF class. Try again using a non-DMTF resource URI.
At line:21 char:5
+     Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer -ComputerName $server |`
I've looked around on this but could not find anything relevant. I've tried with `Get-WmiObject`and that worked fine, but was really slow, approx 10 minutes for 2 hosts :D

Comment: @GaelLacour This error seems to imply you are running PowerShell version 2.0 (or the servers you query have that version). If that is the case, any chance of upgrading PowerShell?

Comment: @GaelLacour I have edited my answer. The new code now uses `Invoke-Command` so the servers themselves do the heavy lifting. Hopefully this is faster that doing it all from your machine. Let me know please?